# Invoke cordova specific code from external page on the server

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

When my cordova app is launched I have redirected the app to my server web app using InAppBrowser plugin,the flow works fine as my web app,but I want to provide a button on the server code which on being clicked should invoke a plugin for instance consider Toast like this

```
window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Hi! you are trying to access cordova plugin from external link')
```

consider the code like this

```
<button id="toast_btn">Show Toast</button>

$('#toast_btn').click(function(){
    window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Hi! you are trying to access cordova plugin from external link')
});
```

but currently it is not able invoke the toast

I would appreciate any sort of help on this issue,since I would follow the same method for my future development.

Comment: As you are using InAppBrowser, you can't execute any plugin from there. If you instead of using InAppBrowser, do a javascript redirect to your website, then it might work if you have all the cordova files on your server too (cordova.js and plugins js), but cordova.js is different for each platform, so you should find a way to load the required one based on the user agent

Answer (score 0):

Like it has already been answered over here:

1. [Calling Phonegap/Cordova plugin functions from remote web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913936/calling-phonegap-cordova-plugin-functions-from-remote-web-page)
2. [Call phonegap plugin function within web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123604/call-phonegap-plugin-function-within-web-app)

**You're not able to invoke plugin commands from an external webpage** like you try because you don't fulfill the requirements for calling a plugin. (`cordova.js` / `whitelisting` etc.)

Comment: The answers for those questions are also same "WE CANNOT",by the way the code I will write in the web-app will be used only by the cordova app & in any case I cannot place the whole web-app code inside the mobile app, so please suggest me a way where **on plugin request I should halt the web-app,execute the cordova based functions,send the response to web-app & finally resume the web-app flow.**

Comment: & thnks for your help

Comment: that would be to much for an answer in my opinion. Maybe it is possible to resolve that via ajax request callbacks. Sorry